# php code to display SUM of rows and column

Tags: php

Database table contain below data. I am selecting total count of receipt no and group by surveyor name.

This works fine:

```
surveyor   bookingdate     receipt_no
 raj       19-03-2015        55
 raj       19-03-2015        55
 raj       19-03-2015        55
 raj       19-03-2015        55
 raj       19-03-2015        55
 raj       19-03-2015        55

 raj       19-03-2015        56
 raj       19-03-2015        56
 raj       19-03-2015        56
 raj       19-03-2015        56
 raj       19-03-2015        56
 raj       19-03-2015        56

sudnyesh    20-03-2015       700
sudnyesh    20-03-2015       700
sudnyesh    20-03-2015       700
sudnyesh    20-03-2015       700
sudnyesh    20-03-2015       700
sudnyesh    20-03-2015       700

RAJ         20-03-2015       701
RAJ         20-03-2015       701
RAJ         20-03-2015       701
RAJ         20-03-2015       701
RAJ         20-03-2015       701
RAJ         20-03-2015       701

angel       24-03-2015        702
angel       24-03-2015        702
angel       24-03-2015        702
angel       24-03-2015        702
angel       24-03-2015        702
angel       24-03-2015        702
```

Current output:

```
 surveyorname   19-03-2015   20-03-2015   24-03-2015      

  raj              2             1            -           

  sudnyesh        -              1            -

  angel            -              -           1
```

I only need is to display sum like below example.

Expected output:

```
surveyorname   19-03-2015   20-03-2015   24-03-2015    TotalSUM

 raj              2             1           -             3

 Sudnyesh         -             -           1             1

 angel            -             -           1             1

 TotalSum         2            1            2             -
```

Code:

```
<?php $book = $database->getRows("SELECT DISTINCT bookingdate FROM receipt_entry"); ?>
    <?php $data = $database->getRows("select surveyor_name, count(DISTINCT receipt_no) As total,bookingdate from receipt_entry group by surveyor_name,bookingdate"); ?>
    <table border="1px solid #666" style="text-align:center;" cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Surveyor Name</th>
            <?php foreach($book as $date):?>
                <?php $dates[] = $date['bookingdate'];?>
                <th><?php echo $date['bookingdate'];?></th>
            <?php endforeach;?>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php $j = 0;?>
        <?php foreach($data as $key => $value):?>
            <?php $names[] = $value['surveyor_name'];?>
            <?php $uniValues = array_count_values($names);?>
            <?php if($uniValues[$value['surveyor_name']] == 1):?>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <?php echo $value['surveyor_name'];?>
                </td>
                <?php $i = 0;?>
                <?php foreach($book as $date):?>
                    <td align="center">
                        <?php if($names[$i] == $data[$j]['surveyor_name']):?>
                            <?php echo $data[$j]['total'];?>
                        <?php else:?>
                            <?php foreach($data as $dat):?>
                                <?php if($dat['surveyor_name'] == $names[$j] && $dates[$i] == $dat['bookingdate']):?>
                                    <?php echo $dat['total'];?>
                                <?php endif;?>
                            <?php endforeach;?>
                        <?php endif;?>
                    </td>
                    <?php ++$i;?>
                <?php endforeach;?>
            </tr>
            <?php endif;?>
            <?php ++$j;?>
        <?php endforeach;?>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Add database schema with data, show actual result and expected result.

Comment: i update my database structure with data...and also current and expected output..in my post...

Comment: I'm working on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your data is formatted like so:

```
$book = array(
    array('bookingdate' => '20-03-2015'),
    array('bookingdate' => '21-03-2015'),
    array('bookingdate' => '22-03-2015'),
    array('bookingdate' => '23-03-2015'),
);

$data = array(
    array(
        'surveyor_name' => 'raj',
        'total' => '2',
        'bookingdate' => '20-03-2015'
    ),
    array(
        'surveyor_name' => 'angel',
        'total' => '1',
        'bookingdate' => '21-03-2015'
    ),
    array(
        'surveyor_name' => 'raj',
        'total' => '1',
        'bookingdate' => '22-03-2015'
    ),
    array(
        'surveyor_name' => 'test',
        'total' => '3',
        'bookingdate' => '23-03-2015'
    ),
    array(
        'surveyor_name' => 'test',
        'total' => '2',
        'bookingdate' => '20-03-2015'
    ),
    array(
        'surveyor_name' => 'test',
        'total' => '3',
        'bookingdate' => '22-03-2015'
    ),
);
```

Then, have your HTML `<table>` layout like so:

```
<?php
// total calculation
$totalSurveyor = $totalBook = array();
foreach($data as $key => $value) {
    $totalSurveyor[$value['surveyor_name']] += $value['total'];
    $totalBook[$value['bookingdate']] += $data[$key]['total'];
}
?>
<table border="1px solid #666" style="text-align:center;" cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Surveyor Name</th>
        <?php foreach($book as $date):?>
            <?php $dates[] = $date['bookingdate'];?>
            <th><?php echo $date['bookingdate'];?></th>
        <?php endforeach;?>
        <th>Total</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <?php $j = 0;?>
    <?php foreach($data as $key => $value):?>
        <?php $names[] = $value['surveyor_name'];?>
        <?php $uniValues = array_count_values($names);?>
        <?php if($uniValues[$value['surveyor_name']] == 1):?>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <?php echo $value['surveyor_name'];?>
            </td>
            <?php $i = 0;?>
            <?php foreach($book as $date):?>
                <td align="center">
                    <?php if(array_key_exists($i, $names) && $names[$i] == $data[$j]['surveyor_name']):?>
                        <?php echo $data[$j]['total'];?>
                    <?php else:?>
                        <?php foreach($data as $dat):?>
                            <?php if($dat['surveyor_name'] == $names[$j] && $dates[$i] == $dat['bookingdate']):?>
                                <?php echo $dat['total'];?>
                            <?php endif;?>
                        <?php endforeach;?>
                    <?php endif;?>
                </td>
                <?php ++$i;?>
            <?php endforeach;?>
            <td>
                <strong><?php echo $totalSurveyor[$value['surveyor_name']];?></strong>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php endif;?>
        <?php ++$j;?>
    <?php endforeach;?>
    <tr>
        <td><strong>Total</strong></td>
        <?php foreach($book as $value):?>
            <td>
                <strong><?php echo $totalBook[$value['bookingdate']];?></strong>
            </td>
        <?php endforeach;?>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

So you can have your expected output:

[image]